# Eclipse not using the lastest snapshot in maven archetype project creation

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-archetype

The title pretty much sums it up, when I create a new project from a maven archetype it gets an old version of the archetype when I use snapshots. Is there any way to force the updating of the snapshots or at least specify which snapshot I actually want?

Answer (score 1):

I have run in similar issue w.r.t to dependent jars, and finally I think it was the corrupt workspace problem. Creating a new workspace worked for me. Hope it helps.

Comment: I believe the problem is with the update policies of maven, if I'm not mistaken the default is to never update. When you create a new workspace the maven archetypes are downloaded again and it takes the newest value. If there is no other option I can live with this, but I rather not need to change workspace (and lose all my workspace configurations) every time I need to test an archetype.

Comment: I believe you mean the preferences by "_workspace configuration_". If yes, then they can be exported into a file and imported back easily.